# How to add Knowledge Component to Case Page Layout (LEx)?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to add the Knowledge Component to a Case page layout in LEx.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_lightning_sidebar.htm&type=5
The above article states:"TIP The Knowledge component isn’t limited to the console. You can add it to apps with standard navigation too. Add the Knowledge component to a record's page using the Lightning App Builder."

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000273151&language=en_US&type=1
The above article gives the step-by-step instructions for adding the Knowledge component to a Case page layout. The issue for me is that when I get to Step 5 (5. From Lightning components search for Knowledge component.) - I'm not finding the Knowledge component.

What am I missing?  How do I add this Component for Case?  (Goal is to replicate the Solutions functionality from Classic...I want to be able to search for, attached, and detach Knowledge Articles.)

thanks
chris

Comment: Have you enabled lightning knowledge?

Comment: I missed the most obvious first step - thanks!